# Outlook Addin FormRegion closing event or similar?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to update some outlook appointment item data (Subject and location to be specific) just before the inspector closes.

From [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/22181ee8-dcf2-43ee-b6ed-d5a1c669201e/) I found out that the closing event sequence is:

1. checks the status of the underlying item to see if it needs saving or not
2. if yes does the write
3. then calls the form region close handler

I need to get some code running before step 1 executes.

The only events I know of around this region is OutlookFormRegion.Close, but this is already too late step 1 and 2 have already passed by then.

The formregion (A C# form with a C# usercontrol) itself does also not fire an event before this modification check.

In essence I am looking for the clos**ing** event instead of the clos**ed**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the appointment data, then why not just update the subject etc and do a Save() on the object from the close handler?  That means it could be written twice, but at least you get your info into the right place.

Comment: I limited my example to just that data, but in fact the appointment contains other fields as well (stored xml serialized in a custom property) The main issue I have for which I need a closing eventhandler is that if you now edit a textfield and then close the inspector not a single event gets fired before the closed event. (no Leave, no Validating, no onvalidated, no inspector.pagechange) the textfield (if databound) does not update the underlying data source as well. So now I can open the appointment, go to my custom form, modify someting and then close, and nothing will have happened.

Comment: Also, the user does not get asked if he wants to save his changes this way. In the closed event I could ask the user if he wants to save his changes, but I can only offer yest and no, not yes, no and cancel. I cannot keep the inspector open like the standard cancel behavior would.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something in your example.  In my app, I have a form region in the appointment inspector.  I handle the onFormRegionClosed event and write my data then.  At that point you could also update the appointment info and call a save().